# unable to extract a table using Beautful soup from Clinicaltrials.gov

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web-scraping and doing some exercises of my on own. I'am trying to extract the table that appears on https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=Activated+Protein+C+Resistance

I tried looking at the script first and didn't find the info there so then I just searched for all table and tried to find the one that has the data I'm looking for

```
url =  "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=Activated+Protein+C+Resistance"
re = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("table")
```

I find two tables, the first one doesn't have the data I'm looking for but the second one has the same attributes as the one that has the data but it doesn't seem to have a tbody?

How do I extract the desired table and generally, What's the correct way to find where the data i'm looking for is located exactly?

Comment: Do you need to be logged in to see the tables? Following the link shows no tables and ruuning the corrected code only returns an empty df with e following columns: ```Individual Patients ```, ```Intermediate-size Population```,  ```Treatment IND/Protocol```

Comment: And you are 100% sure of the url?

Comment: Which table do you want. Post a picture.

Answer (score 0):

The table you are looking for is loaded by javascript, so you have to use a library like selenium. (As side note, naming response re could be confusing as there's a useful library called re)

For this, you'll need to download selenium and chromedriver for your operating system.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
ser = Service(YOUR FULL PATH TO chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=chrome_options)

url =  "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=Activated+Protein+C+Resistance"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

df_tables = pd.read_html(str(soup), flavor="bs4")
```

Because tables is a list of dataframes, you see each one by referencing like any other list.

```
df_tables[0]

                              0
0           Individual Patients
1  Intermediate-size Population
2        Treatment IND/Protocol

df_tables[1]

   Row  Saved      Status                                        Study Title                                       Conditions                                      Interventions                                          Locations
0    1    NaN   Completed  Effect of Resistance Training in Water Combine...                                  Resistance, APC  Other: Resistance training that combines water...                      Guo weiGuyuan, Ningxia, China
1    2    NaN  Terminated  Study With Atezolizumab Plus Bevacizumab in Pa...  MSIColoRectal CancerChemotherapyResistance, APC                Drug: AtezolizumabDrug: Bevacizumab  KU LeuvenLeuven, BelgiumOspedale Niguarda CA G...
```

Comment: This worked for some links but for some others it doesn't show the correct dataframe(the data in the dataframe is basically all over the place). for example this link "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=%2246%2C+XX+Disorders+of+Sex+Development%22" which is still the same website! I tried undersating why but still couldn't find an answer